# How can I convert an ansible inventory to an dnsmasq conf file

Tags: shell-script, ansible

I use ansible-playbook to manage my vps, and put all vps info into an inventory file like below:

```
[base]
vps_virmach ansible_host=127.39.39.34  ansible_ssh_user=root
vps_vulr ansible_host=24.39.48.02 ansible_ssh_user=root

[web]
vps_aliyun ansible_host=114.39.43.55 ansible_ssh_user=root
```

And I have a router running dnsmasq service, and I want to write a **shell script** to generate a conf file for dnsmasq, so I can access the vps with custom hostname.

expected:

```
address=/vps_virmach/127.39.39.34
address=/vps_vulr/24.39.48.02
address=/vps_aliyun/114.39.43.55
```

I have so little shell script programming experience, that I wanna know which command or command pipeline should I pick to get my work done.

Comment: `cat hosts |perl -pe 's|^(\w*) ansible_host=([0-9\.]*) .*|address=/$1/$2|;' |grep ^address= >dnsmasq_out`

Comment: @bitinerant Thank you so much. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create the file in Ansible. The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: conf.txt
        content: |
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
          address=/{{ host }}/{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_host'] }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat conf.txt 
address=/vps_virmach/127.39.39.34
address=/vps_vulr/24.39.48.02
address=/vps_aliyun/114.39.43.55
```

Comment: The idea is great. I do not know that I can use ansible to generate a local file, until you show me. Thank you. But  I would stick to shell script method as I am planning to use some shell script like `scp`, `ssh` to configure my router. Python has not been installed  on my router.

Comment: I see. FYI, there are supported [platforms](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_index.html#platform-options) without Python.

Comment: And I highly recommend [Ansible Role: openwrt](https://github.com/gekmihesg/ansible-openwrt) for configuring OpenWrt routers.